# How to remove hashtable @{ } from the value of a variable?

Tags: powershell, hash, hashtable

How do I remove a hastable from a variable?

I am expecting my $username variable in Write-Warning to only show 'Ginny Pare'. However with my PS script below, it appeared as @{Name=Ginny Pare}.

```
        script: |     
          [CmdletBinding()]
          param (
              [array]
              $namelist
          )

          Import-Module ActiveDirectory
          foreach ($user in $namelist) {
              $samname = $user.SamAccountName 
              $name = $user.Name
              $username = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$samname'" | Select Name
                  if (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$samname'") {
                      Write-Warning "SamAccountName $samname, is already used for user $username. Account creation for $name is unsuccessful."
                  }
                  else {
                      Write-Output "Account creation for $name is successful." 
                  }
          }

        parameters:
          namelist: "{{ hostvars.localhost.namelist }}"      
        error_action: stop
```

My write-warning output is: "SamAccountName Gin.P, is already used for user @{Name=Ginny Pare}. Account creation is unsuccessful."

How do I remove @{Name= }?

**Note:**
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$samname'" will give the output as below. 'Select Name' will extract the 'Name' key and value.

```
DistinguishedName : CN=Ginny Pare,OU=Users,DC=demo,DC=local
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : Ginny
Name              : Ginny Pare
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter of `select` so you only get the string value of the property:

```
$username = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$samname'" | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```